# How to get the count of a cell in a data using Protractor

Tags: protractor, protractor-net

Im unable to fetch the count of a cell of the below mentioned table. I want to fetch the count only in the table body.Please help me to achieve this- Im looking to get the count of-

```html
<td class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0">$0.90</td>
```

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks!!

```html
<div class="show-for-large-up">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
        <th class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0" ng-bind-html="receiptTemplate.paymentFee" width="300">Payment Fee</th>
        <!-- end ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- ngRepeat: lineItem in paymentDetails.responseObject[0].schedules[0].schedule_line_items track by $index -->
      <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="lineItem in paymentDetails.responseObject[0].schedules[0].schedule_line_items track by $index">
        <td class="ng-binding">$45.00</td>
        <!-- ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
        <td class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0">$0.90</td>
        <!-- end ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
      </tr>
      <!-- end ngRepeat: lineItem in paymentDetails.responseObject[0].schedules[0].schedule_line_items track by $index -->
      <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="lineItem in paymentDetails.responseObject[0].schedules[0].schedule_line_items track by $index">
        <td class="ng-binding">Jul 21, 2017</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">$0.00</td>
        <!-- ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
        <td class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0">$1.68</td>
        <!-- end ngIf: paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0 -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What i tried- But im get the count as 3. Actually the count should be 1

```js
var paymentTable = $$('.show-for-large-up tr');
var row = paymentTable.$$('[ng-repeat="lineItem in paymentDetails.responseObject[0].schedules[0].schedule_line_items track by $index"]');
var cell = row.$$('[ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0"]');
var cellCount = cell.filter(function(elm) {
  return elm.count();
expect(elm.count()).toBe(1);
});
```

See image below
[image: Looking to fetch the count of rows for the column Payment fee]

Comment: how are you accessing `elm.count()` outside the filter? are you not getting error?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo while copying the code, edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter will not work because a filter will get the first matching element and doesn't count, see also the [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first)

You could achieve this with a [each](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each). You iterate though each matched element and then do the things you need. You code would look something like this

```js
var count = 0;

// Get all the td's
$$('[ng-if="paymentDetails.responseObject[0].fee_amount > 0"]')
  // Walk through all the found td's
  .each((element) => {
    // Get the text of the td
    return element.getText()
      .then((text) => {
        // Add a + 1 if the text matches
        if (text === '$0.90') {
          count + 1;
        }
      });
  });

// Do the assertion
expect(count).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer wswebcreation, but the amount will not be 0.90 always. amount will be changing for every payment. Please let me know if there is any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just make the amount a variable

Comment: still im unable to achieve the intention of the testcases, could you please help on getting the count of the cells on multiple rows?

Comment: Can you then explain more about what you the testcase is and what you want to achieve,

Comment: Hi wswebcreation, im looking to get the row count for the column named "Payment fee" in the image attached, Could you please help me on this issue. <img> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZKi8.png  Thanks!